# Integrate Struts2 with Spring-Security

Tags: spring, struts2, spring-security

It possible to integrate Struts2 with Spring-Security but without using Spring-core beans?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring-security [depends](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-core/3.1.0.RELEASE) on Spring-core so I think it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

All spring components and sub projects depends on spring core. But I guess you are woried about struts-2. You can easily use struts-2+spring-core+spring security